# Uniform continuity of continuous functions on compact sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Assume that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous function on the compact set $A$.

Does for any $\varepsilon >0$ exist a $\delta >0$, such that 
$$
\lvert\, f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\varepsilon \,\,\,\,\,\,\textrm{for every}\,\,\,\, x,y\in A,\,\,
\text{with}\,\,\, 
\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta?
$$

Comment: Do you mean to say that $f$ is continuous on each compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or just one fixed compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous on a fixed compact $A$.

Comment: Not really, there is the slight problem of when $x\in A$, but $x+t \notin A$. Else it is just trivial since $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: The last edit changed the question by requiring $y \in A$, which makes it much easier (or at least much more familiar).

Answer (score 4):

> Assume that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous on a compact $A$. Then for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$, such that
>   $$
> \lvert\,f(x+t)-f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon, 
> $$
>   whenever $x\in A$, $\lvert t\rvert<\delta$ and $x+t\in A$.

If $x+t$ is not required to belong to $A$, then the value $f(x+t)$ does not affect the continuity of $f$, when restricted on $A$. For example (as in D. Fisher's example above), let
$$
f(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text{if} & x\in A,\\
0 & \text{if} & x\not\in A.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $f$ restricted on $A$ is continuous, while at $x=1$, and $t=1/n$, we have 
$$
f(1+1/n)-f(1)=-1,
$$ 
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

On the other hand, the reformulated claim is just the fact that *continuity on a compact metric space implies uniform continuity.*

Comment: This is an answer to the wrong question.  The question as originally asked is meaningful and has an affirmative answer (see my answer).

Comment: Yes, this example $f$ is *not* continuous on $A$ if this means that $f$ is supposed to be continuous at each element of $A$.  It's continuous on $A$ in the weaker sense that the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is continuous, but that makes the problem much less interesting.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that we can assume that $f$ is identically zero on $A$ by subtracting off a continuous function $g$ extending the restriction of $f$ to $A$. Such a $g$ can be constructed using the distance function $d$ from $x\in\mathbb{R}$ to $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.

The question becomes to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $d(t,A)<\delta$ then $|f(t)|<\epsilon$. Suppose there were no such $\delta$.  Then one can construct a sequence $(t_n)$ with $d(t_n,A)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ while $|f(t_n)|\geq\epsilon$. The sequence is obviously bounded and therefore has a convergent subsequence $t_{n_k}\to x_0$.  Then $x_0\in A$ by compactness. It follows that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$, contradiction.

Comment: +1 for answering the more interesting question that was originally asked (before the last edit).  But I'm unclear on how to define $g$.  We want $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in A$, of course; for $x \notin A$, if there is a unique $y \in A$ such that $d(x,y) = d(x,A)$, then we can use $g(x) = f(y) + d(x,A)$.  There is at least one such $y$, but what if there is more than one?  If we just choose arbitrarily, then how do we guarantee that $g$ is continuous when we switch from one branch to another?

Comment: More explicitly, given $A=\{0,1\}$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and $f$ continuous at $0$ and $1$, what is $g(1/2)$?  (Well, $g(x)=x$ is an obvious choice, but how do you derive that from $f|_A$ and $d(-,A)$?)

Comment: Sorry, one last comment:  I agree that a $g$ exists to complete the proof, by the Tietze Extension Theorem, so I'm fine with your overall answer.  I just don't understand what you were saying about how to construct $g$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is called Heine's theorem, here goes my attempt:

First note that your condition is equivalent to: $$\exists\delta>0 : \forall\varepsilon>0, x,y\in A  \Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon, \text{if } |x-y|<\delta$$
Which also means $$\forall\varepsilon>0, (x_n),(y_n)\subset A, \ \lim(x_n-y_n)=0 \Rightarrow |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|<\varepsilon$$
Also I'll use the definition of compact by sub-successions, which is that: $$\forall (x_n)\subset A, (x_n) \text{ succession, then there exists a convergent sub-succession} (x_{n_k})\subset A, \text{and} \\ \lim x_{n_k}\in A$$

So, first suppose that $f$ is *not* uniformly continuos, so we negate the previous statement:
$$
\exists\varepsilon>0, (x_n),(y_n)\subset A : \ \lim(x_n-y_n)=0 \Rightarrow |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\ge\varepsilon \tag{#}
$$
So, let $(x_{n_k}), (y_{n_k})$ be convergent sub-successions, with $(x_{n_k})\to x_0$. Since $\lim(x_n-y_n)=0 \Rightarrow (y_{n_k})\to x_0$. Now use the fact that $f$ is continuos$^*$, in which case $$(f(x_{n_k}))\to f(x_0), f(y_{n_k})\to f(x_0). \text{Therefore, }\lim(f(x_{n_k})-f(y_{n_k}))=0.$$
Using the definition of limit this contradicts condition $\text{(#)}$, therefore $f$ is uniformly continuos. Note that by replacing "$|$" with "$||$" we obtain the generalization for metric spaces! (because the succession characterizations also hold).

$*\text{using $f$ continuous} \Leftrightarrow \forall (x_n)\mid\lim(x_n)=p, \ \lim f(x_n)=f(p). $

Comment: This only answers the question after the subsequent edits by Yiorgos, not the original (more interesting, less duplicated) question.